# How to fill a matrix in R based on turns of X and O (like in tictactoe game)?

Tags: r

Hi i would like to make a function that fill a 3x3 matrix, like the tictactoe game, where i replace each element of the matrix (in random positions) with an X or O, starting form X.
I tried this code:

```
sample.space <- c(0,1)
theta <- 0.5 # this is a fair prob
N <- 9 # 

flips <- sample(sample.space, 
                size = N, 
                replace = TRUE, 
                prob = c(theta, 1 - theta))`
```

but this code generates an already filled matrix, not respecting the turns. In other words i want to stop when i find just one winning combination.

Comment: Just assign a number 1 to 9 for each of the squares and then shuffle the numbers 1-9 (`sample(1:9)`). That will give you a random order in which the squares were filled in. If you assume X was first, you should be able to reconstruct the board from that. It's unclear from your description to be exactly how you plan to use this or what output you really need though.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(4)
m = matrix("", 3, 3)
turns = rep(sample(c("X", "O")), length.out = 9)
spots = cbind(rep(1:3, 3), rep(1:3, each = 3))[sample(1:9),]
for(i in seq_along(turns)){
    m[spots[i,1], spots[i,2]] = turns[i]
    C1 = any(apply(m, 1, function(x) sum(x == "X") == 3) |
                 apply(m, 1, function(x) sum(x == "O") == 3))
    C2 = any(apply(m, 2, function(x) sum(x == "X") == 3) |
                 apply(m, 2, function(x) sum(x == "O") == 3))
    C3 = sum(diag(m) == "X") == 3 | sum(diag(m) == "O") == 3
    C4 = sum(diag(t(m)) == "X") == 3 | sum(diag(t(m)) == "O") == 3
    if(C1 | C2 | C3 | C4){
        break
    }
}

m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "X"  "O"  ""  
#[2,] "X"  "X"  "O" 
#[3,] "O"  "O"  "X"
```

Comment: It returns alway the same matrix. I was looking to generate each time a different matrix

Comment: Thanks so much man, you are great. Sorry for the last question but i am new to R and don't understand very much what i do eheh